# "no endpoint listening" WITH "no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, xaml, enterprise

We are having a rather intermittent issue with our enterprise application where were are getting an "EndPointNotFoundException" that we could not find the issue. However, on some off chance while debugging the solution we came acrossthe error and were able to grab the inner exceptions. I should note that before we got this error there was a communication error right before it (for a task manager) but the data for that was not captured, unfortunately.

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/GetData.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at PROGRAM.DataServices.IGetData.GetUserLoggedInStatus(String userID, String fullName)
       at PROGRAM.DataServices.GetDataClient.GetUserLoggedInStatus(String userID, String fullName) in C:\PATH\Reference.cs:line 3419
       at PROGRAM.BusinessLayer.clsUtilities.CheckLoggedInStatus(String userID) in C:\PATH\clsUtilities.cs:line 438
       at PROGRAM.DashBoard.Timer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\PATH\clsDashboard_Events.cs:line 99
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.StartDispatcherInBrowser(Object unused)
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
       InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
            HResult=-2147467259
            Message=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:1346
            Source=System
            ErrorCode=10061
            NativeErrorCode=10061
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
                 at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

We think it might be our contract with services being violated for that connection when ever it fails since it "ACTIVELY" ignores the request but other than that we are not sure.

Comment: On face value of the exception, the end point which your code is calling doesnt exists. Try using WCF client (if you are using wcf) to test that if the end point does exists and responsing. Or use Fiddler to check the end point.

Comment: it exists but its a service we remotely connect to. This is a rather rare occurrence that we have no idea how to recreate (this happened on a chance and did nothing, to our knowledge, different than we would normally when testing). Based on the inner exceptions it DOES exist but it's just not letting us communicate with it.

Comment: The exception has url "http://localhost/GetData.svc" which says its trying to connect locally....correct me if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: I was debugging from Visual Studios so yes, it created a local host. HOWEVER, this has happened on the live application, though I cannot post the full url for that for security reasons, of course. It calls out to something remotely from GetData.svc

Comment: "InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
       Source=System"

Comment: We are having a similar problem.  It is very intermittent (occurs every couple of weeks) and impossible to reproduce in a debuggable situation.  There is no apparent correlation to any events that we can see, and we've been looking for about 8 months.  End-point definitely exists on the server, because usually most of the engines can, and do, connect to the server,  but perhaps 50% or so are sometimes inexplicably unable to connect.  Did you find your problem?  It started after installing a (large) collection of MS patches last February (which may or may not be relevant).

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh we are hoping that when we convert to .Net 4.5 that this issue might resolve itself. I am sorry that we have not further pinpointed a solution.